# Dataweave: Filter XML payload based on staring value starting with specific character

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have an input XML which has a list of suppliers and some other data. The input XML looks like:

```
             <screenFields>
                <ScreenFieldDTO>
                    <fieldName>SUPP1</fieldName>
                    <value>123</value>
                </ScreenFieldDTO>
                <ScreenFieldDTO>
                    <fieldName>MAKE1</fieldName>
                    <value>ABC</value>
                </ScreenFieldDTO>
                <ScreenFieldDTO>
                    <fieldName>SUPP2</fieldName>
                    <value>234</value>
                </ScreenFieldDTO>
                <ScreenFieldDTO>
                    <fieldName>NORM2</fieldName>
                    <value>TXT2</value>
                </ScreenFieldDTO>
                <ScreenFieldDTO>
                    <fieldName>SUPP3</fieldName>
                    <value>124</value>
                </ScreenFieldDTO>
                </screenFields>
```

I want to filter this XML to access the values of field names which start with 'SUPP'.
I know the filter in dataweave can compare the entire value but I need to filter field names containing specific string.

The mapping looks like:

```
 %dw 2.0
 output application/json
 fun filterSupplier(val) = if(val startsWith("SUPP")) "SUPP" else ""
 ---
{
"fieldname": payload.screenFields.*ScreenFieldDTO filter $.fieldName == 
 (filterSupplier($.fieldName))
}
```

The expected response is:

```
{
 [
  {"fieldname" : "SUPP1", "value": "123"},
  {"fieldname" : "SUPP2", "value": "234"},
  {"fieldname" : "SUPP3", "value": "124"}
 ]
}
```

The response is coming as blank. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: The expected output is invalid JSON. You can't have an object containing an array without a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script that you are using is overly complicated for the filter. `filter()` just requires an expression that returns true or false, so simply `filter ($.fieldName startsWith("SUPP"))` will work and expresses the intention much more clearly.

I'm assuming that the expected output is an array. I would also added a map to change the key name in each element of the array to `fieldname` as in the expected output.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.screenFields.*ScreenFieldDTO 
    filter ($.fieldName startsWith("SUPP"))
    map {"fieldname": $.fieldName }
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "fieldname": "SUPP1"
  },
  {
    "fieldname": "SUPP2"
  },
  {
    "fieldname": "SUPP3"
  }
]
```